# Use WebStorm diff tool with TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, webstorm, tortoisehg

Is there any way to use WebStorm diff tool with TortoiseHg?

I've tried to set `vdiff =  /usr/local/bin/wstorm` in `.hgrc`, but it didn't help.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/working-with-webstorm-features-from-command-line.html?search=command#d278336e319

Answer (score 1):

- You must perform more jobs, if you want to use external diff with [Extdiff extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension)
- **Now** custom diff tool can be added to Mercurial without this extension: read `[merge-tools]` section in `MergeTools.rc` for any merge-tool, but note only *diff keys, namely `diffargs`, `diff3args`, `dirdiff`

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable invocation of WebStorm operations from the command line as instructed [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-webstorm-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html) (so that you can execute `webstorm` from the Terminal).
2. Put the followings to your `.hgrc` file:

---

```
[extensions]
extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.wsdiff = webstorm
opts.wsdiff = diff
```

---

3. (bonus) Make WebStorm as your default merge tool:

---

```
[ui]
merge = webstorm

[merge-tools]
webstorm.check = prompt
webstorm.args = merge $local $other $base $output
```